# Access object property value by UnaryExpression

Tags: c#

How can I obtain the object property value by matching the UnaryExpression "Member name" **without** using "direct" reflection?

```
public object DoSomething<T>(UnaryExpression uExp, T obj)
   {            
        object res = null;                       
        // NOTE: UnaryExpression contains a property from T type.
        // TODO: get UnaryExpressionMatchingProperty value

        // res = obj.UnaryExpressionMatchingProperty;
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: `uExp.Operand as MemberExpression`, and then get the member details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should produce the value or `null` if the structure of the unary expression is not as expected:

```
var prop = ((uExp.Operand as MemberExpression)?.Member as PropertyInfo);
if (prop?.CanRead == true) { // Needs "== true" because ?. makes Nullable<bool>
    res = prop.GetValue(obj);
}
```